# How to make the text bold in message dialog?

Tags: java

How to make the text bold in message dialog? Here is my code

```
private void tentangActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "SISTEM PAKAR \n"
            + "adalah suatu sistem yang menggunakan ilmu, fakta dan teknik berpikir seorang ahli \n"
            + "dalam mengambil keputusan untuk menyelesaikan masalah-masalah yang biasanya \n"
            + "hanya dapat diselesaikan oleh ahli dalam bidang yang bersangkutan.");  
}
```

Comment: Where is your custom dialog layout?

Comment: Please put your code into Code Block.

Comment: Sorry, it's the first time I post here.

Comment: it's solved, thx for the answer

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
JOptionPane
        .showMessageDialog(
                this,
                "<html><strong> SISTEM PAKAR <br />"
                        + "adalah suatu sistem yang menggunakan ilmu, fakta dan teknik berpikir seorang ahli <br />"
                        + "dalam mengambil keputusan untuk menyelesaikan masalah-masalah yang biasanya <br />"
                        + "hanya dapat diselesaikan oleh ahli dalam bidang yang bersangkutan.</strong></html>");
```

Use HTML tags to make the message **bold** and replace `\n` with `<br/>` tag

Comment: Sorry, posted the answer at the same time.

Answer (score -1):

You should enclose the text string in a html tag and use aditional style tags:

```
private void tentangActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "<html><b>SISTEM PAKAR <br/>" + 
        "adalah suatu sistem yang menggunakan ilmu, fakta dan teknik berpikir seorang ahli \n" + 
        "dalam mengambil keputusan untuk menyelesaikan masalah-masalah yang biasanya \n" + 
        "hanya dapat diselesaikan oleh ahli dalam bidang yang bersangkutan.</b></html>");
}
```

Comment: thx for the answer, it's work!

Comment: and how to change the font size for title (SISTEM PAKAR)?sry i don't know    about php's rule.

Comment: you can put the text arround `<span style='font-size:2em'>` tag.

Comment: sry it's not work, can u tell me how to write it?